# What circuit is used in industry for SCR firing?

Tags: power-electronics, scr

I am a hardware developer. I have a requirement for designing a firing card for SCR. I am not very used to using thyristors and it has been a long time since I used one.

I see on the internet there are typically R, RC, and UJT circuits for the firing of SCR.

Can you tell me what circuit is typically used in the industry for robust design for SCR firing?

Comment: You may want to ask a more specific question. There are hundreds more ways to fire a card.

Comment: SCR are fired with "power pulses". Depending of kind of SCR, kind of load, etc ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydjqG.png  Sorry, in french

Comment: I don't think UJTs have been used in decades; as far as I know, they aren't even manufactured anymore.

Comment: Yes ... UJT (very few models after 2N2646), after some years, was quickly replaced by PUT ...

Comment: You can trigger the SCR with a pulse, a string of pulses or DC, depending on requirements and allowable gate dissipation. You may have to meet specific requirements for the trigger pulse (high current and fast rise time) if it's a very high power SCR in order to prevent failure due to hot spots. Generating the pulses is much easier than it was 50 years ago- you could  use a microcontroller or whatever, then drive the gate either directly or through some kind of galvanic isolation.

Comment: All industrial SCR boards I had ever seen, do use pulse transformers for the gate triggering and a train of pulses, if that's what you are asking for.

Comment: "Safety" first ... and pulses pass easily  through a transformer ...

Comment: @MarkoBuršič How are the Pulses typically controlled? Are they controlled using Micro controllers or UJT/PUTs ?

Comment: https://www.dynexsemi.com/Portals/0/assets/downloads/DNX_AN6148.pdf?ver=48i47757-88pDhO4o8jhQA%3D%3D   FIGURE 4

Comment: See also this file for old firing SCR methods : https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics_technical/application_notes/switching_thyristor/littelfuse_triggering_and_gate_characteristics_of_thyristors_application_note.pdf  figure 1-24

Answer (score 1):

Here an example of such "drivers" : SCR is fired every 20 ms (50 Hz EU)

[image]

NB :

1- A guard angle ( generally 15-30 °) must be provided (firing angle no more then 150 degrees) ... especially in case of inductive load.

2- The simulation does not show the "synchronization" circuitry.